# TCP Server-Client disconnects after a single transmission

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

I'm working on a Server-Client program for school and using a given code for the TCP connections.
The client side:

```
void func(int sockfd) 
{ 
char entryArr[MAXSIZE][MAXLEN];
int n,c;
int i = 0;
char entry;
char iEntry[1];
char id[6];
char fname[5];
char lname[5];
char score[4];
for (;;) { 
    bzero(id, sizeof(id));
    bzero(fname, sizeof(fname));
    bzero(lname, sizeof(lname));
    bzero(score, sizeof(score));    
    printf("[1] Add a Student \n");     //Menu
    printf("[2] Display ID \n");
    printf("[3] Display Score \n");
    printf("[4] Display All \n");
    printf("[5] Delete an Entry \n");
    printf("[6] Exit \n");
    printf("Please Select from the Menu: ");  //get menu selection
    scanf("%1s", iEntry);   //read entry

    if (iEntry[0] == '1') //if entry = 1
    {
        getchar();
        printf("\n------Add a New Student------  \n"); 
        printf("\n6-Digit ID: "); 
        scanf("%6s", id);           //read 6 digit id

        while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );
        printf("Student's First Name: "); 
        scanf("%5s", fname);                //read first namae

        while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );

        printf("Student's Last Name: "); 
        scanf("%5s", lname);                //read last name
        while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );
        printf("Student's Score: "); 
        scanf("%3s", score);                //read score

        while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF );

        write(sockfd, iEntry, sizeof(iEntry)); //write entry number
        write(sockfd, id, sizeof(id));          //write id
        write(sockfd, fname, sizeof(fname));    //write fname
        write(sockfd, lname, sizeof(lname));    //write lname
        write(sockfd, score, sizeof(score));    //write score
        printf("\n------Student Added------\n");
        i++;

    }
int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

    addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;
    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

    func(sockfd);

    close(sockfd); 
}
```

Server side:

```
void func(int sockfd) 
{ 

int i = 0;
char idArr[MAXSIZE][MAXLEN];
char fnameArr[MAXSIZE][MAXLEN];
char lnameArr[MAXSIZE][MAXLEN];
char scoreArr[MAXSIZE][MAXLEN];
char entryArr[MAXSIZE][MAXLEN];
char iEntry[1];

char id[6];
char fname[5];
char lname[5]; 
char score[3]; 
int n,c;
char entry;
// infinite loop for chat 
for (;;) {
    printf("HERE6\n");
    bzero(iEntry, sizeof(iEntry));
    bzero(id, sizeof(id));
    bzero(fname, sizeof(fname));
    bzero(lname, sizeof(lname));
    bzero(score, sizeof(score));
    read(sockfd, iEntry, sizeof(iEntry));
    strcpy(entryArr[0], iEntry);
    if (iEntry[0] == '1')
    {
        read(sockfd, id, sizeof(id));

        read(sockfd, fname, sizeof(fname));
        read(sockfd, lname, sizeof(lname));
        read(sockfd, score, sizeof(score));
        printf("HERE5\n");
        strcpy(idArr[i], id);
        strcpy(fnameArr[i], fname);
        strcpy(lnameArr[i], lname);
        strcpy(scoreArr[i], score);

        printf("Student Added.\n");
        i++;
}
int main()
{
int sockfd, connfd;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
socklen_t addr_size;

sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
if(listen(sockfd,5)==0)
    printf("Listening\n");
else
    printf("Error\n");
addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);

func(connfd); 
close(sockfd); 
}
```

in my func() function I am running a menu with options. The program works as expected when it is running on the same terminal using PuTTy (i.e eros.tx.state.edu).
When I run on two different terminals (on the same machine) the program works but exits as soon as it reaches the first write().

Any idea why does this happen?
sorry for the long post I tried to keep it to minimum.

Comment: "ignores the loop in the func() function". What loop? You didn't show the `func` code so we it would be difficult to guess why an unseen loop would exit. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as required for Stack Overflow debugging questions.

Comment: "When I connect to two different server (on the same machine)". Did you run the same server code? You can't bind two processes to the same port number so that would not work.

Comment: Both sides are sending and neither is receiving. Doesn't make much sense. Almost complete lack of error-checking in the code.

Comment: The func() works perfectly fine. this is why I did not include it. When I run them both on eros.txstate.edu everything works as expected. But when I log from two different servers the program stops after the server reads the received data.

Comment: If it worked fine then wouldn't that mean it should work in all cases? Since it doesn't then could it be that it is not as fine as you think? By definition you don't know where the problem is and experience shows it is unproductive to debug incomplete code that we can't run for ourselves. Hence the requirement for a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: I might not explaining myself correctly. The only issue is the connection between the client and server when connected from different servers. I tested it hundreds of times on the same server and there is no problem sending and receiving data. I just fail to understand how different servers cause the program to interrupt.

Comment: Then probably should answer my second question.What do you mean by "different servers"? Each port can only be bound to one server (e.g. you can't run two web servers using port 80 on the same machine)

Comment: I am using PuTTy to connect two servers in my school. I run the client on eros.txstate.edu and the server on zeus.txstate.edu. When I run both client and server on the same school server (eros)it works fine.

Comment: Both `read()` and `write()` return a value. You can look up in the manual what they mean. And how you could act on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
char iEntry[1];
```

Okay, `iEntry` contains a single character.

```
read(sockfd, iEntry, sizeof(iEntry));
strcpy(entryArr[0], iEntry);
```

Why are you passing `iEntry` to `strcpy`? It's a single character. How are you expecting `strcpy` to know that it should only copy a single character?

Why not just test `iEntry[0]`? Why is `iEntry` an array anyway?

Your code ignores the return value of `read`. You, at a minimum, need to handle short reads by writing some kind of "read all" function that reads in precisely the number of bytes specified.

Comment: Even when I comment this out the result is the same. The code immediately exits when it reaches to the first write() on client side.

Comment: Did you fix the `serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");`? Did you add error checking to functions like `connect`, `bind`, `listen`, and so on?

Comment: This was a given code. I did not alter it. The server stays at "Listening" and client exists when it tries to write()

Comment: With no error checking, there's no way you'll be able to figure out why it doesn't work. Functions return values for a reason.